# is there an oauth2 provider who is essentially anonymous (but might store credit card information)

Tags: oauth, paypal, oauth-2.0

Not sure if this is right place to ask but...

The title sums it up - we are looking for an oauth2 provider that doesn't have the baggage of a Facebook or Twitter but does provide oauth2. A bonus would be some form for credit card integration (although a distant requirement) Does paypal or stripe offer something like this?

thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal Access is what you may be looking for https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/getting-to-know-paypal-access. 
Can you explain the credit card integration piece?

Comment: this is an interesting product from them. I have the feeling this is what we'd be looking for; however, the only issue would be marketing / UX rather than technlology. PayPal, in my mind, has a pretty limited focus in only doing transactions and, ideallly, we are looking for identity first and payments second. In all honesty, I'm surprised the larger providers such as FB or Google don't really provide this better

Comment: The UI has been cleaned up. When you log in to developer.paypal.com you go through PayPal access flow (aka Log In With PayPal). If you have some feedback please share. I work for PayPal and I can pass it on to our Product folks.